# How to solve this error in eclipse after importing any project

Tags: android, import, project

I have just imported my old project. But it shows error. I am not getting what type of error this is and why. and how to solve it. Anyone can give me idea how to resolve it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project name, --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path...

Check Projects and Libraries Tab, the reason for the red exclamation mark is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a simple refresh solves the problem, also you can check the Problems view
Window -> Show View -> Problems

Comment: Hello friend. I tried refresh but it does not. But I got my solution. And thank you so much for answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because missing of dependent jars in path,if the path is to the local machine.
Check it in build path. It is the only problem i faced 99 times out of 100..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Path of the library added.

Right-click on the project name, --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path.